# Gruping with Banded Grid

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

How can I get the attached image with a banded grid? Could you help? Or share a small sample?

Pic link: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/8c8c9b2e-5a20-4992-b146-d21d541fc6f7

[image: Table image.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style is named "Advanced Banded Grid View" and is [documented over here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114637/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Banded-Grid-Views).

[image: Advanced Banded Grid View]